# Responsive Menu Issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design

Hi I have a responsive menu system that works great, but now I want to change the URLs positions in a different way, first take a look at my dropdown menu here..

http://jsfiddle.net/Et2HB/

Actually I need to give Main Menu 1, Main Menu2 and Main menu 3 to separate links like one for www.example1.com, one for www.example2.com.. Although I just want the dropdown function just above the right down arrow(nav_sprite.png) which you can't find in the jsfiddle example. You can see that in the below class

```
ul#menu li.hasChildren a > span {
  background: url(../images/nav_sprite.png);
  background-position: right 0px !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px auto;
}
```

I tried to add another anchor tag like the following..and gave that  tag to float:left and tried to add width 55px to the second anchor tag which for drop down and to the right side by given float:right. But it all collapses like hell.....

```
<li><a href="http://www.example.com">Main Menu 1</a><a href="#" tabindex="1" accesskey="h">&nbsp;</a>
<ul>
....
```

Do you have any idea to resolve this?

Thanks Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly. Take a look at my jsFiddle:

**[Fiddddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Wa2e/1/)**

The trick is to give the *"li"-Element* a *position: relative* attribute.
Then you're free to position your dropdown-button-element absolutely:

**CSS:**

```
ul#menu li a.dropdownBtn {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu" class="overthrow">
    <li><a href="#" tabindex="1" accesskey="h">Main Menu 1</a>
        <a class="dropdownBtn">v</a>
        <!-- etc etc -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
// change:
$('ul#menu li.hasChildren a').on('click', function() {
// to:
$('ul#menu li.hasChildren a.dropdownBtn').on('click', function() {

// and change:
if($(this).attr('class')=="hasChildrenActive"){
// to
if($(this).hasClass("hasChildrenActive")){
```

The only thing what's left then, is to adapt your js-code so that it uses the a.dropdownBtn instead of the other link-tag.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but still I can see the whole <li> tag has drop-down function, how to give a link to the text 'Main Menu 1' and then I want a gap without url I mean drop down function till the ' v ' on right side..

Comment: As I wrote: What's left is to adapt the JS. Please see the updated Fiddle-Link. I guess it's still not 100% as you want it. But this platform is for answering questions, not demanding coded solutions.

Comment: Nirazul, I'm sorry if you feel my reply like 'do it for me' type.. actually I'm playing it around with this whole day... I appreciate your quick response and Thanks again..